# Pipelines and git-ftp dirt repository error

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use Pipelines with git-ftp to push files to my remote server.

Error message:

> fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting...

YML file:

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - git ftp init --user USER --passwd PASSWORD ftp://user@mydomain.tld@ftp.mydomain.tld/
```

I also tried `git ftp push` but same thing.

There are no uncommitted changes, so what gives?

Comment: Are the uncommitted changes on the destination side?

Also: is there some specific reason you have to use FTP instead of a secured method?

Comment: FTP because it's a cheap shared host. As for uncommitted changes, no, there shouldn't be, the destination is only ever receiving files. Unless the fact im running composer is messing it up? I just want to upload files, clean every time.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to debug changes that made your repo dirty add line to your script graph:

`- git status -uno --porcelain`

If it returns you something this means, in virtual deploy server some changes happen. For example, some files was corrupted while sending to over server

`png, jpeg, exe, jar, etc`

in order to fix it add lines into .gitattributes

`*.exe binary
*.jar binary
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.gif binary`