# FTP-Deploy-Action : fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting

Tags: github-actions

In my github project, i have used the config below :

```
- name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.0.0
      with:
        ftp-server: sftp://${{ secrets.HOST }}${{ secrets.PATH_PROJECT }}
        ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USER }}
        ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        git-ftp-args: --insecure
```

But on the step `FTP-Deploy-Action`, i get this error :

> fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting...

**NB :**

- Yes, i'm sure that my change is commited and pushed
- Because of this is runned by github action, `git status` make no sense (cause github actions clone the repo to a **new env** before `git ftp push`, which produce the error)

[Github FTP-Deploy-Action issue link](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/68)

For information, i have already read these link :

- https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/327
- [Getting fatal: Dirty repository: Having uncommitted changes. Exiting... in Pipelines with git ftp push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565212/getting-fatal-dirty-repository-having-uncommitted-changes-exiting-in-pipel)
- [Pipelines and git-ftp dirt repository error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46697367/pipelines-and-git-ftp-dirt-repository-error)

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem too. It may be that your build process changes tracked files.

I added `git reset --hard` before running FTP-Deploy-Actions. Following [this tutorial](https://stephanwagner.me/deploy-websites-with-bitbucket-pipelines-and-git-ftp)'s recommendations.

I'm very junior so there may be a better way I don't know of.

Comment: Thnks, I will test it

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, and discoved that after the `npm install` step, the `package-lock.json` file is updated, so the repository get dirty, you can check if it is your situation adding a `git status` step before the ftp step:

```
      - name: git status
        run: git status -uno --porcelain
```

Im my case, if I reset the `package-lock.json` file before the FTP step the problem is solved:

```
      - name: reset package-lock.json
        run: git checkout package-lock.json
```

Comment: Thnks, I will try it

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, as I was doing some appsetting transformation.

Then I found [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-action) and it worked for me.

```
- name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: sebastianpopp/ftp-action@releases/v2
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}${{ secrets.PATH_PROJECT }}
        user: ${{ secrets.FTP_USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        forceSsl: true
```

Deppending if your user has access to the root directory you also might want to change it to

```
- name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: sebastianpopp/ftp-action@releases/v2
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        user: ${{ secrets.FTP_USER }}
        password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        remoteDir: ${{ secrets.PATH_PROJECT }}
        forceSsl: true
```

Note that instead of sftp:// I added a "forceSsl". I didn't needed it in my case.

Comment: Thks, I will test it

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm not posting this as a comment because I don't have the required reputation yet.

I was having the same issue. And as @fegnus, I encounter that after the `npm install` step, the `package-lock.json` file gets updated.

I solved the issue by replacing the `npm install` command with `npm ci`.

The `npm ci` will do the following things:

1. It will delete your `node_modules` folder to ensure a clean state.
2. It will look in your `package-lock.json` to install all the dependencies with the exact version.
3. Unlike `npm install`, `npm ci` will never modify your `package-lock.json`. It does however expect a `package-lock.json` file in your project — if you do not have this file, `npm ci` will not work and you have to use `npm install` instead.

Remember that the `package-lock.json` is generated when we do `npm install` on the development machine. And this file should be tracked by git.

References:

1. [Ali Kamalizade](https://medium.com/@ali.dev) - [npm ci vs. npm install](https://medium.com/better-programming/npm-ci-vs-npm-install-which-should-you-use-in-your-node-js-projects-51e07cb71e26).
2. Similar issue in [another project](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues/1495).
3. Official `npm ci` [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html).

Comment: Thnks, I will try it